# SQL query to extract date from constant format string

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, extract

**The problem**: due to horrific design, the date are stored as strings. The format is consistent though.

The string always is stored as:

```
Revised: dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 §
```

For example:

```
Revised: 09/01/2019 00:00:00 §
```

**Desired solution:** I need to extract the dd/mm/yyyy and convert to date if possible.

**Additional Info**: I don't know what that squiggle is. I actually have to convert the column using `convert(nvarchar, <field1>, 103)` to get above output. This is because I use `SELECT DISTINCT` clause and need to avoid getting below error message:

> Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: what is your db name?

Comment: it is called schemedatabase

Comment: As the error says: the `ntext` datatype is horrible, and cannot be used as a "normal" string. You need to **first** convert `ntext` to  `nvarchar(max)` - **then** you can use `DISTINCT` on that data

Comment: I have the output: "Revised: 09/01/2019 00:00:00 §". How do I get the date part out?

Answer (score 0):

Since it follows a strict pattern, you can simply replace the bits that are not part of the datetime, and convert afterwards:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(255) = 'Revised: 09/01/2019 00:00:00 §'

SELECT  @test --Original value
,       REPLACE(REPLACE(@test, 'Revised: ', ''), ' §', '') --Replaced value
,       CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(REPLACE(@test, 'Revised: ', ''), ' §', ''), 103) --Converted value
```

Since your datatype is `ntext`, you'll have to convert it to `varchar` first.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is for one field. I need for the column as I can't be declaring all that.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila, of course, this was just an example. Instead of `@test`you can have your column (converted to `varchar`).

Answer (score 0):

That can be done simply by

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(LEFT(YourColumnName, 10) AS DATE) AS Result
FROM YourTableName;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03359819f0583d34de18c9bd9b7794de)**

If `Revised:` in the string you can do as

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(YourColumnName, 'Revised: ', ''), 10) AS DATE) AS Result
FROM YourTableName;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddf00f464c7b3f2ff4966c6f13e7e3cb)**

Comment: @HoneyBadger Does _Revised:_ in the string? If so I'll update.